# Office Web Apps Server - XML Page doesn't work - The Webpage cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, office-web-apps, dns, owa

I have an issue with Office Web Apps Farm. I created an SharePoint environment (DC+SQL Server, SharePoint Server and Office Web Apps Server). All went well until i had to configure OWA Server. OWA installed without any error (clean installation), i configured the server, but when i try to test //server/hosting/discovery, any browser give me "Webpage not found" after the browser asked for my credentials. I checked the Office Farm status with the command: Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine and the status is Healhy. I don't understand why is the address not working since i had no errors durring the installation and the farm status is Healthy. I used the following procedure to install OWA - HTTP only:

1.

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Static-Content,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Security,Web-Filtering,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-App-Dev,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Includes,InkandHandwritingServices,NET-Framework-Features,NET-Framework-Core,NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

2. Run the Setup file. OWA [image: IsoImage]
   3.

   > New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "servername" -AllowHttp
   >   -EditingEnabled New-WOPIBinding -ServerName owa -AllowHTTP

​ - on SP Server
4.
Testing //server/hosting/discovery - The Webpage cannot be found
[image: Not found]
I went forward and :

```
(Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig).AllowOAuthOverHttp
$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

I don't understand why is this not working since i've done it already last month on my old SP Evironment and it worked with the same settings. i can ping OWA server from DC or SP servers, everything seems to be connected. What could went wrong this time? Please help me!!